# How to split the content of a DIV tag to multiple DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `DIV`tag with specific Width and height attributes.

```
<div style="width:793px;height:1096px"> A long text and pictures</div>
```

I want to separate the `DIV tag` to multiple `DIV tags` when the lines and pictures are exceeded the first `DIV` and want to show the remaining text and pictures in next `DIV` instead of having overflow and scrolling.

how to do it?

Comment: How do I understand the content is exceeded from the first div and cut the remaining to the next div?

Comment: so you want to read more button after some text or image, so you can try `overflow:hidden`

Comment: else try if($('div').width > your value) then append it

Comment: i don't have just word to count it.

Comment: Do you know what the reporters do?? they paging the content when it exceeds.

Answer (score 0):

like this way [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/9ckc4/)

```
$('ul.expander li').expander({
  slicePoint: 50,
  widow: 2,
  expandEffect: 'show',
  userCollapseText: '[^]'
});
```

​